# How to find out whether a PhD dissertation is ready to submit?

Tags: phd, thesis, advisor, thesis-committee

How one may know that his/her work is good and enough for getting PhD? Does it depend on the number of words, pages, number of published paper or some things else?

Comment: By definition, your work is good enough for a PhD when your thesis committee signs the paperwork.

Comment: In most situations that I've seen, a thesis is complete when the adviser says that it is.  Other members of the thesis committee or (in my department) members of the department's doctoral committee can, in principle, still raise objections, but this is very unusual.  In 45 years of teaching, I remember only two cases where the thesis committee raised a question and none in which the department's doctoral committee raised a question.

Answer (score 3):

You should talk about this with your advisor and your consultant professors. You can complete your report and show it to your advisers. They will read and tell you what lacks in your report. Also, you may talk to the members of your PhD committee orally before giving them your report. They may give you some guides or some of their expectations.

Talk to the previous PhD students and see what brought them to the point that their PhD was ready to be presented.

Another important thing is your PhD proposal in which you have clarified your goals of your dissertation. If you have completed your promises in the proposal (or you have strong reasons why could not reach some of your goals), then your work is completed.

Another thing may be regulations of your department. Some departments require their students to submit one or two journal or conference papers out of their PhD project. You can check your department's regulations on what are their expectations from a complete PhD project.

Comment: @Nora I am not sure but it may be a good idea to see what are your funding provider's expectations on your final PhD dissertation.